# A task using django/heroku scheduler do nothing

Tags: python, django, heroku, task, scheduled-tasks

I have used heroku to deploy using python-django.
Following heroku documentation, i installed scheduler, create a python scrypt(tarefas.py), but nothing happened.

the log show status 0.
this is the heroku help answer:

Anuj Pandey

20 hours ago

Hi Carlos,

The status 0 signifies that the entire process is completed and everything worked fine. As logs also show your tarefas.py and python tarefa2.py are executing completely.
The issue seems to be with the code you have pushed, this appears to be an issue that falls outside the nature of the Heroku Support policy. I recommend searching our Help Center or asking the community on Stack Overflow for more answers.

Regards,
Anuj Pandey

tarefas.py:

```
import smtplib
import email.message
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ERP.settings')
def EnviarEmailTeste():
    texto = '<h1>Teste de agendamento de tarefas a cada 10 minutos</h1>'
    msg = email.message.Message()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Teste de agendamento de tarefas'
    msg['From'] = '*****'
    msg['To'] = '****'
    password = '****'
    msg.add_header('Content-Type','text/html')
    msg.set_payload(texto)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
    s.starttls()
    s.login(msg['From'],password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'],[msg['To']],msg.as_string().encode(('utf-8')))
    s.quit()
    context = 'email enviado com sucesso.'
    return context
```

my heroku scheduler:

```
Job             Dyno Size           Frequency   Last Run    Next Due     
$ python tarefas.py
                    Standard-1X    Every 10 minutes October 17, 2023 11:32 AM UTC   October 17, 2023 11:42 AM UTC
$ python tarefa2.py
                     Standard-1X   Every 10 minutes October 17, 2023 11:32 AM UTC   October 17, 2023 11:42 AM UTC
```

log:

```
2023-10-17T11:32:17.871269+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python tarefas.py` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
2023-10-17T11:32:24.506888+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python tarefa2.py` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
2023-10-17T11:32:24.611632+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4184]: Starting process with command `python tarefas.py`
2023-10-17T11:32:25.168610+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4184]: State changed from starting to up
2023-10-17T11:32:26.719784+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4184]: Process exited with status 0
2023-10-17T11:32:26.745531+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4184]: State changed from up to complete
2023-10-17T11:32:30.775330+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8591]: Starting process with command `python tarefa2.py`
2023-10-17T11:32:31.390275+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8591]: State changed from starting to up
2023-10-17T11:32:31.955033+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8591]: Process exited with status 0
2023-10-17T11:32:31.987920+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8591]: State changed from up to complete
```

How can i fixed that and this script send a e-mail each every 10 minutes?

This function its a test. I have tried send a e-mail each every 10 minutes, but i do not received any e-mail.
How can i fixed that and send a e-mail every each 10 minutes using heroku scheduler and Python-Django?

Comment: Is there more in that file? You're defining a function, but you aren't calling it. Before trying to schedule it, make sure it does what you want by running it interactively: `heroku run python tarefas.py`.

Comment: No,just that.  Runing heroku run python tarefas.py(Manually in cli) or schedulling like i wrote above, the answer is the same(log). I don't now what i can do about it.

Comment: Again, you haven't _called_ the function anywhere. This has nothing to do with Heroku, it would behave the same way on your local machine. See the marked duplicate.